# add click listener to multiple buttons at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

As the title, I'm trying to add click listener to multiple buttons at once.
but when I try source below, Listener added successfully, but it doesn't open any links. I mean socialLinks array is undefined when the function add listener to each elements. can someone help me?

```
$('.IndexBody').arrive('#shortUrl', function(){
        var shortUrl = $('#shortUrl').text();
        var socialTags = ['.entypo-twitter', '.entypo-facebook', '.entypo-gplus'];
        var socialLinks = ["http://twitter.com/share?text=http://"+shortUrl+" — Link made by ",
                           "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+shortUrl+"&amp;src=sdkpreparse",
                           "https://plus.google.com/share?url="+shortUrl];
        console.log(socialLinks);
        for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
          $(socialTags[i]).click(function(e) {
            var width  = 575,
                height = 400,
                left = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
                top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
                opts   = 'status=1' +
                         ',width='  + width  +
                         ',height=' + height +
                         ',top='    + top    +
                         ',left='   + left;
            window.open(socialLinks[i], 'facebook', opts);
            console.log(socialLinks[i]);
            return false;
          })
        }
      });
```

Comment: Should `" — Link made by "` be escaped?

Comment: `$(socialTags.join(',')).on('click', HANDLER)`

Comment: http://ignaciothayer.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are capturing `i` inside a [closure](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp), so it's value when the button is clicked will be the current value, not the value when you created the function.

Try something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
  $(socialTags[i]).click(createHandler(socialLinks, i));
}

function createHandler (socialLinks, i) {
    return function (e) {
        var width  = 575,
            height = 400,
            left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
            top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
            opts   = 'status=1' +
                     ',width='  + width  +
                     ',height=' + height +
                     ',top='    + top    +
                     ',left='   + left;
        window.open(socialLinks[i], 'facebook', opts);
        console.log(socialLinks[i]);
        return false;
    };
}
```

Comment: Would `handler()` be called within `for` loop?

Comment: Yeah, handler is *executed* while you are looping, and *returns* a function which executes when the button is clicked.  This way, the value of `i` during the loop (the value you want) is stored in the argument to the handler function (also called `i`).

Comment: `handler` would probably be better named `createHandler` - updated.

Comment: This is probably the most common problem people have when coming to Javascript from other languages.  Closures are incredibly powerful once you get the hang of them :)

Comment: I just tried this. socialLinks array seems work. but click listener is not added to buttons. It doesn't do anything when I click buttons

Comment: Are you sure you have elements on the page with classes `.entypo-twitter`, `.entypo-facebook` and `.entypo-gplus`, and that you've waited for the DOM to load completely before this code runs?  Try putting some `console.log()` statements in the code and see what order they appear in your console.

Comment: I tried ```for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
          console.log($(socialTags[i]).length);
          $(socialTags[i]).click(handler(socialLinks, i));
        }```

Comment: @AlexMcMillan and it prints 1. so they definitely exist.

Comment: and I don't know why, In for loop, It only execute when 'i' is 3.

Comment: and it opens  "https://plus.google.com/share?url="+shortUrl even though I didn't click anything.

Comment: Try learning about closures and asynchronous functional programming.  It's important you understand the basics to know whats wrong here.